# Is it possible to output log data in Exressjs?

Tags: express

I'm developing a small MEAN application and I'm running into a problem when I'm trying to delete or update an record.

book.component.ts

```
deleteBook(id) {
  this.api.deleteBook(id)
    .subscribe(res => {
        this.router.navigate(['/books']);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
}
```

api.service.ts

```
deleteBook(id: string): Observable<{}> {
  return this.http.delete(`${apiUrl}/${id}`, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

This is the output from the command line for ExpressJS and Angular:

```
[1] [HPM] Rewriting path from "/api/5b0e61859a51ca1cc05ef819" to "http://localhost:3000/api/5b0e61859a51ca1cc05ef819"
[0] DELETE /api/5b0e61859a51ca1cc05ef819 500 0.180 ms - -
[1] [HPM] DELETE /api/5b0e61859a51ca1cc05ef819 ~> http://localhost:3000
```

In the browser console is get this:

> Backend returned code 500, body was: null

This is my /routes/book.js delete function:

```
router.delete(':/id', function(req, res, next) {
  Book.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next (err);
    res.json(post);
  })
})
```

So it looks like the id is passed to backend correctly but it looks like the req is empty in the book route?

Is it possible to log what is happening on the ExpressJS side of things?

Comment: You call `next(err)`, and you should process that error somewhere. Show the code where you process app errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a logger, like [`morgan`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan).

Add the dependency with `npm i morgan` to your server, then add morgan as middleware:

```
var morgan = require('morgan');
// Standard Apache combined log output
app.use(morgan('combined'));
```

Another logger you might want to use is [`winston`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston).

Or add this before all other routes:

```
// Only in development
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req);
    next();
  }
}
```

Edit: Do you use [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)?

Comment: I thought that wasn't needed with `app.use(express.json());` Also I've tried Winston.  `winston.log('debug', 'Now my debug messages are written to console!');` this does show up in the console. But this in my delete function doesn't show up `winston.level = 'debug'; winston.log(req.body);`

Comment: Just tried replacing `express.json` with `bodyParser.json` but the result is the game.

Comment: Have you added body-parser with `app.use(bodyParser.json());`? And have you tried my last suggestion? Maybe you will need to add some more code to your question.